# How to run .out file at linux startup with user input?

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi

I have rspbery pi 0 and main.cpp:

```
while(true)
{
   cin >> temp;
   if(temp)
      MyFunction(temp);
   else if(temp == 2)
      MyFunction2(temp);
   else
      cout << "Text\n";
      MyFunction3(temp);
}
```

I already compiled this program using g++ to main.out and now
I am trying to start this program automatically after Pi boots up

Comment: Will any of these help? https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/

Comment: `after Pi boots up` `with user input?` So  how is "user input" going to be inputted? `and main.cpp:` C++ is not Python. `MyFunction3` is going to be executed always. Do you mean you want to run your program as a shell?

Comment: I have card reader that simulates keyboard so i was thinking it would be inputted in console.
also good point with MyFunction3 i have already fixed that.